# Flash Player Setting Problem

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, flash-builder

I am building a flash app that will asks the client to access their web camera.
Users on Windows (Firefox, Safari, Chrome browsers) are able to click the allow button.

However, users on Linux/Mac (Firefox, Safari, Chrome) either need to click several times until they can click allow, or they can't click at all.

According to this forum, it has something to do with the CSS.
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/24111?tstart=0

Anyone know how to fix this exactly?

Thanks!
Hiro

Comment: Have you tried removing the padding/margin and changing the text-align as they mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did try all of the things, but it sometimes go better (meaning required fewer clicks) or got worse (unable to click at all)